# In the result of the analysis of the SONARQUBE server does not show correctly the Total of lines of code and nor the errors of code

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I am using SERVER: SONARQUBE V.5.6.6 and our old code is in C#, we use Plugin 5.0 -> (SonarQube Scanner: sonar-csharp-plugin-5.0 - and scanner: sonar-scanner-3.0 - Command Line Analysis ). With this plugin 5.0 the lines of code and values of the metrics for each file are shown correctly, but when updating the server with the 5.9 plugin (sonar-csharp-plugin-5.9.0.1001 - Command Line Analysis) - This new plugin Does NOT completely detail all lines of code Nor the values in (Bugs, Code Smells, Duplications) for each file.

(SONARQUBE V.5.6.6) - Analysis C # with Plugin 5.9 -> (SonarQube Scanner: sonar-csharp-plugin-5.9.0.1001 - Command Line Analysis) - This new plugin does NOT completely detail all lines of code Nor the values in (Bugs, Code Smells, Duplications) for each file.

The structure of our project is composed of several layers and in each layer are the modules. The file properties "sonar-project.properties" is in the root of the project at General level, with the other plugins previous to version 5.0 we had no problem whatsoever, for this reason we are working with version 5.0.

How can we solve this?. Since these results obtained affect the quality indicator as it shows as if there was no error in the code, but really if there are cases to adjust.

see: (Analysis with Plugin 5.9 vs Plugin 5.0)
[Analysis with Plugin 5.9 vs Plugin 5.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxZjU.png)

Comment: Why do you have a "sonar-project.properties" file? For .NET solutions, you should use the SonarQube scanner for MSBuild => https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-msbuild.html

Comment: Not long ago we started with the sonarqube code review using the sonnar-scanner by command line, and with the plugin until version 5.4 the analysis worked correctly, from that moment on, the Totals of analysis results were affected, since It seems as if it does not recognize some files that in an earlier version if they were recognized.

Comment: Well, we won't be able to support you if you're not using what we recommend. For .NET projects, that's a no-brainer: you must use SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild otherwise you will have side effects.

Comment: Ok, so I'll do a lab using MSBuild scanner and I'll see how it goes in the scan results.

Comment: -I already updated Sonarqube 6.5, with sonar-csharp-plugin-6.3.0.2862 plugin and MSBuild scanner, I also checked the installed java version and it's Java8.-I have run our analysis in our project, but it still appears files that are not read completely, it does not detect them (bugs, code smell, duplications). The error still persists and we have stopped this process of reviewing code rules because the information that shows the SONARQUBE is not reliable because it is not 100% Correct.
-If it is necessary to make another ticket, let me know.-See: <http://prntscr.com/g9cap2>